# How to use VBA to Get result from an Access fuzzy query?

Tags: vba, ms-access, fuzzy-search

Database just like

- Id name
- 1 aaa
- 2 bba
- 3 aac
- 4 ddb

In Access query design I use

```
select * from dbname where name like '*'& [The Name ?] &'*'
```

to do the fuzzy search, it works all right.

But when I use this query in VBA ,it's just get nothing back.

```
Public Sub SeekClientData()
Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRs As ADODB.Recordset

Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set adoRs = New ADODB.Recordset

With adoConn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\fsdb.mdb"
End With

adoRs.Open "[testquery]'aa'", adoConn    'testQuery


Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset adoRs


adoRs.Close: Set adoRs = Nothing
adoConn.Close: Set adoConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I debug this code, I just get adoRs.EOF.

But When I set it strict, I mean no fuzzy, It works all right.
I mean this:

```
select * from dbname where name=[The Name ?]
```

works right.

I have done a lot search, but can't solve this.Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Range(A2)?  Sounds like Excel.  ThisWorkbook.Path also sounds like Excel.  Is this strictly in Access?  Is it a hybrid?

Comment: programming in ms-VB6 get the same result.